# Will Billy Batson grow up to look like Shazam?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, shazam

In *Shazam* the child Billy Batson is able to transform into the eponymous hero that is an **adult-like** character in **looks (face + body)**.

But do we know if Shazam's look is Billy Batson's future look? I mean, will Billy grow up to become a person who looks like Shazam or does Shazam have a random appearance?

Comment: Shazam is a adult muscular man because of the magical powers he have, mostly from Herculese and Appolo (from the powers he inherit when becoming Shazam), AFAIK we don't know how Billy will looks like when he grown up, nor probably we'll see it in DCEU

Comment: Not the DCEU, but in "Kingdom Come", adult Billy looks like Captain Marvel (as the character was being called at the time).

Comment: @user888379 As far as I know the change in name (Cap Marvel to Shazam) was only due to Marvel copywrites. It had nothing to do with the looks. Cap marvel was the alter ego / superhero version of Billy Batson who was later named SHAZAM.

Answer (score 6):

As Shazam (aka Captain Marvel) has been around for close to 80 years, there have been a number of iterations of the character. In at least one major version, we learn that Billy's Captain Marvel identity is a dead ringer for his late father.

[image]

In the ***Power of Shazam!*** series from the mid 1990s, writer Jerry Ordway identifies Billy's parents as C.C. and Marilyn Batson, a pair of married archeologists who were murdered by Theo Adam, a thug working for the evil Doctor Sivana. As you can see from the image above, C.C. looks pretty much identical to Captain Marvel. Likewise, Marilyn is depicted as looking very much like Mary Marvel, the alter ego of Billy's sister, Mary Batson.

My interpretation of this revelation has always been that Billy would grow up to look just like his father, but that's just conjecture on my part.

Comment: So, SHAZAM resembles his deceased father? That's a new piece of information. Thanks [UPVOTED].

Comment: Have you read the other issues by Jerry Ordway? From what I remember there is one where Billy and Mary (his sister) give some of their power to Freddie, who has been badly hurt, but Freddy stays a kid after the transformation. The wizard explains that it's because subconsciously Freddy thinks that's how the best version of him looks like (i.e. the same as he is, just with more muscles).