# Do Shazam and Man of Steel exist in same universe?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel, shazam

In the mid-credit scene, we see Shazam invites Superman to his school in the lunch break.

From previous knowledge, we know that Shazam has been a part of the Justice League. But there was no cameo of any of the Justice league character in the film, and that of Superman is faceless.

Do these two films exist in the same universe under the same franchise?

Somewhere on Youtube (a review channel), I heard, Henry Cavill didn't have dates for Shazam, was that the real reason?

Comment: Are they really calling the character Shazam?

Comment: @BenPlont There needs to be a side character that relentlessly teases him for the name. "Isn't there a better name you can use?"  Played by Brie Larson...

Comment: @BenPlont what else would the main character in a movie called _Shazam_ be called (I know the Marvel issue).

Comment: @BenPlont they didn't even use the name Captain Marvel in *Captain Marvel*.

Comment: @OrangeDog But we know from our knowledge that the character Carol Danvers is _Captain Marvel_ and so is Billy Batson known to us as _SHAZAM_

Comment: @RC0993 the point is Billy Batson is also Captain Marvel. SHAZAM! is the magic word.

Comment: @OrangeDog I am not 100% sure but `Billy Batson was*...`. There was a copyright issue widely known about that now. Offically DC cannot use Cap.Marvel name for Billy now. So that Character was adapted as Shazam after the same Magic word.

Comment: @RC0993 no, they cannot title the work *Captain Marvel* but they are allowed to use the character name. They just choose not to, to avoid confusion. Regardless, we're just joking around as both movies are out around the same time.

Comment: @OrangeDog Ohh that's new info for me. I didn't know about that.And obviously! all comments are being taken in healthy spirit. Even I am enjoying this discussion

Comment: @OrangeDog What are your views on [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98176/will-billy-batson-grow-up-to-look-like-shazam)?

Comment: I was talking with my six- and nine-year-old sons after the movie about how he could introduce himself, "Hello, I'm Shazam." "AAAGH... Lightning strike! Hey, where'd that super dude go?" I'm pretty sure he stuck with Captain Sparklefingers. That's the last thing he was called in the movie.

Comment: @OrangeDog [Here is a link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/how-does-shazam-tell-people-his-name) that says the character's name is Shazam as he uses it to introduce himself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Do these two films exist in the same universe under the same franchise?**

Yes, and it has been said many times. Such as from [indianexpress](https://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/hollywood/shazam-connected-dc-film-universe-zachary-levi-5496786/):

> The movie is completely trackable on its own merit. That said, there a lot of fun little nods/homages/Easter eggs that can be enjoyed should one be caught up in the DCEU.”- Zachary Levi

Even [director discussed](https://www.indiewire.com/2019/04/shazam-post-credits-scenes-what-they-are-david-f-sandberg-1202056610/) about Aquaman joke too.

From [Rrunpee](http://runpee.com/is-shazam-part-of-the-dc-universe-or-a-stand-alone-film-can-shazam-fix-the-dceu/):

> According to every reliable internet source, Shazam is indeed set within the larger universe of the DC superheroes, at least from the ‘official DCEU starting point’ with Man of Steel, in 2013.

And they also list other sources too:

> **Screenrant says:** the producers went to great lengths to only show background action figures the DCEU featured to date, holding back on
>   characters they haven’t allotted movie time to yet. It’s a deliberate
>   thing. It’s world-building.
>
> **ING.com reports:** “So while Superman was battling Zod and then Batman and then Doomsday and then death and then Steppenwolf, Billy
>   Batson was being tossed around the foster care system.”

Also from [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/shazam-dceu-appearances-justice-league/):

> In an interview with Entertainment Weekly, Shazam! producer Peter Safran said "I wouldn’t be surprised to see Shazam play a role in the DCU. He exists in that world." What's more, there is already a plan in place, should the character make further appearances in other films. Since actor Asher Angel, who plays young Billy Batson in the film, will continue to grow up at a rapid pace, there is a contingency to make this all work. "It’s something we’ve considered and have plans in place for sequels that take into account those realities," Safran teased.

I might have missed many other such interviews but I guess you got the point.

**Henry Cavill didn't have dates for Shazam, was that the real reason?**

Yes, he was not available, from [inverse](https://www.inverse.com/article/54562-shazam-ending-explained-directors-talks-about-superman-without-henry-cavill):

> “And, of course, I wanted Henry Cavill to pop up. But he was unavailable, which was disappointing.”
>
> Sandberg remembers feeling vexed. “It’s the end of the movie. What are
>   we going to do?” Determined to stick as close as possible to the
>   original idea, he enlisted Zachary Levi’s stunt double to wear
>   Superman’s costume and opted to shoot the Last Son of Krypton only
>   from the neck down. It didn’t calm Sandberg’s nerves, however.
>
> “We had Zack’s stunt double do it, but I was worried. Is this gonna
>   feel cheap? Is this not gonna work? To cut before you see his face, is
>   this gonna feel cheap? Are people gonna feel cheated?”
>
> Later on in post-production, Sandberg finally relaxed when he saw the
>   scene cut together.
>
> “It just made us laugh,” he says. “You see Freddy’s reaction and a
>   hard cut to credits, and it’s just funny. It turned out better than
>   what it was originally, where he sat down and had a little chat.”

Comment: `completely trackable on its own merit` is his personal opinion. Is there any particular reason for not having a cameo? It literally showed Superman faceless, why not just get Cavill to potray his own character? I suppose your answer is acceptable as it is directly towards the question. I will wait for sometime before accepting it though.

Comment: @RC0993 it's low budget film and affording cameo maybe tough for them. And Cavil might be out of DCEU, we never know

Comment: @RC0993 updated with more info

Comment: [UPVOTE] That's insightful. Although `it's low budget film and affording cameo maybe tough for them` I still don't buy this to be true (more like a guess). But I liked the research behind this answer. :)

Comment: @RC0993 I dig but no interview why Cavil not there and why costume was not same as JL film. I will dig more later

Comment: https://movieweb.com/henry-cavill-superman-statement-warner-bros/